# Is Geovisualization API compatible with JavaScript 3.1 SDK?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

it seems that the Geovisualization is not compatible with the JS Framework 3.1 of your mapping SDK. Are you planning on updating it ?
Or can you provide a replacement ?

Here is the link to the doc used: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geovisualization/dev_guide/topics/overview.html

It supposed to be used by adding this Script :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/2.6.1/mapsjs-datalens.js"></script>
```

And the error with the new version:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RenderEngine' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:12)
    at e (mapsjs-datalens.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:12)
    at e (mapsjs-datalens.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:12)
    at e (mapsjs-datalens.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:8)
    at e (mapsjs-datalens.js:8)
    at mapsjs-datalens.js:8
    at mapsjs-datalens.js:8
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what exactly do you mean by `Geovisualization` and how is it not compatible with HERE Javascript API 3.1?

Comment: Added the details to the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Geovisualization API is not compatible with latest HERE JavaScript API 3.1 and there is no plan to update it.

But current `HERE JavaScript API` is capable of 95% Geovisualization use-cases.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex1hz6y5/) example for animated markers example (based on [Geovisualization](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/geovisualization/technology_animation/animated-markers) example)

Comment: My main use case is animating fluidily markers, as shown here : https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/geovisualization/technology_animation/animated-markers

All the other ways that I tried were flaky animations, where I was deleting and creating markers to simulate animation, which was really poor UI wise and performance wise.

Also I'm using the heat map with adjustable bandwith https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/geovisualization/technology_heat_maps/heat-map-bandwidth

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with jsfiddle link which shows Animated Markers similar to `Visualize Animated Markers` example.
Regarding heatmaps, can you please share a data set to use?

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I'm looking for, it's unfortunate that it's not integrated to the SDK as before.

For the Heatmap, I based my code on this example: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/geovisualization/technology_heat_maps/heat-map-bandwidth but I'm not using the fetchQueryStats, I just want to achieve the same effect visually where the points are aggregated when the zoom is low and detailed points when the zoom is high

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no,  Geovisualization/Data Lens API is not compatible with JS API 3.1. At the moment there are no plans to update or replacing the same.