# Choropleth (datalense) map possible with incompatiblity of Geovisualization API and JavaScript 3.1 SDK?

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to create a choropleth map with JS 3.1 and Geovisualization?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993889/is-geovisualization-api-will-be-compatible-with-javascript-3-1-sdk) says JavaScript 3.1 and Geovisualization is incompatible.

What i want is such a map:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/geovisualization/technology_choropleths/choropleth-country-gdp-geojson

I tried following code in typescript inside index.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/latest/mapsjs-datalens.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And get following error:

```
mapsjs-datalens.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RenderEngine' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at n (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at n (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at n (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at n (mapsjs-datalens.js:7)
at mapsjs-datalens.js:7
at mapsjs-datalens.js:7
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a screenshot of the map from the example. The page was online at sunday. The example was about a dataset with an certain country value and another one with the gps coordinates of the country borders. The example should simply make a choropleth map.

[Screenshot of HERE choropleth map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB3Q3.jpg)

**EDIT2:**

In the example they use following data for the country shapes by an spatialProvider:

```
let spatialProvider = new H.datalens.RawDataProvider({
            dataUrl: 'https://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/datasets/here_country_low.json?' + Date.now()
        });
```

For the value they also use a example dataset in form of an dataProvider:

```
 var queries = {"query":{"fileName":"query.json","dataset":"379fe7b20d1444b197340da02df6239f","id":"0a9c6e3996944984b36232547602baf4"}};
    const {query} = queries;  

 let dataProvider = new H.datalens.QueryProvider(
        service,
        {
            queryId: query.id
        }
    );
```

The colour is separated by d3

```
let values = [0, 0.24, 0.86, 2.42, 10];
let colors = ['#2A3691', '#3F5CA5', '#57A4D9', '#97D3CA', '#CAF8BF'];
let colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile().domain(values).range(colors);
```

**EDIT3:**

I am beginning to think that is't not possible to create such a coropleth map with HERE maps. The whole geovisualization area is no longer available at the homepage of HERE. That's a heavy statement i think.

Maybe someone of the HERE technology team can answer this question?

Comment: Can you describe what was the example about? It seems there is some problem with geovisualisation on here developer portal:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geovisualization/dev_guide/topics/overview.html

Comment: Thank's for your info. I add a description of the example to my question. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Yes. it's easy to do. Can you share the data country shape colors should be based on?

Comment: Please see EDIT2 inside the question. Thanks

Comment: O.K. Thanks. Do you know what could that dataset be?

Comment: 1) Open the link and you will see the dataset for the countryshapes 
2) I don't know what the dataset is. But for the example they import the dataset and then only choose one column. That it's just a vector with values ...you can take random values between 0 and 100.

Comment: @Tomas Did you find out anything? Have you any idea how to implement such a map? It would be enough to display the map with a local dataset if the problem is at the providers or queries.

Comment: sorry had vacation, will check.

Comment: @Thomas Did you get it done?